# How to determine if a cell has scrolled off screen XCUI

Tags: swift, automated-tests, xcode-ui-testing

I have a XCUI test case in swift where I am trying to determine if a cell has scrolled off screen. However, I've noticed that once a cell has been on screen the static text is always findable, even when the cell scrolls off screen, when using

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.tables.cells.StaticText["person"].exists)
```

This also does not work for me

```
let window = app.windows.elementBoundByIndex(0)
let element = app.tables.cells.staticTexts["person"]
XCTAssertTrue(CGRectContainsRect(window.frame, element.frame))
```

As that second test will pass, even when the cell has scrolled off screen.

Is there a way to determine whether a table cell is no longer within the view on the screen?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't more than one "person" cells? This assertion should fail if the cell is actually off the screen.

Comment: There is more than one cell. It's basically a list of names within a table of cells. Each cell shows the basic info for a person and then additional information once tapped. Also there is no where else on the screen that shows the text "person" once it has scrolled off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this problem, kind of clunky but works, is that I used a function like this

```
func tapOnSpecifiedPointOnList(cellNumber: Float) {
    let cellSpacing: Float = 75
    let xCoordinate: Float = 25
    let yOffSet: Float = 90
    let yCoordinate = yOffSet + (cellSpacing * cellNumber)
    let pointToTap = CGPointMake(CGFloat(xCoordinate), CGFloat(yCoordinate))
    map().tapAtPosition(pointToTap)
}
tapOnSpecifiedPointOnList(0)
let startingCell = app.cells.otherElements["callout"].elementBoundByIndex(0).label
app.cells.otherElements["callout"].swipeUp()
for i in 0...numberOfCells {
    tapOnSpecifiedPointOnList(i)
    let nextCell = app.cells.otherElements["callout"].elementBoundByIndex(0).label
    XCTAssertNotEqual(startingCell, nextCell)
}
```

When a cell was tapped, it opened up a separate callout, which didn't exist before. By attaching an accessibilityId on this callout object, I was able to grab the info from the cell and compare it to other cells which I tapped on. Therefore, if I tapped on all possible cell locations on screen, and none of callouts matched the original, it must have gone offscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`hittable` API on XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement/1500561-hittable) to determine if an element both exists and is on screen. You should use it on the cell.

**Note:** `hittable` will become `isHittable` in Swift 3.

```
let cell = app.tables.cells.containingType(.StaticText, identifier: "person").elementBoundByIndex(0)
XCTAssertTrue(cell.hittable)
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me. Even if I try to fail the test by attempting to tap the cell while it is off screen, it just autoscrolls to the cell and taps it anyway.

Comment: What behaviour are you trying to test? Does the cell return false for hittable when it is off screen?

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the cell has gone off screen. I was able to find a work around by checking to see if a lower portion of the list had loaded, since the lower portion would only load if the upper portion had gone offscreen. However it appears that once the list is loaded, it stays that way, making it very hard to determine if the upper cells have actually gone offscreen.

Comment: This may stem from reuse of collection/table view cells. Once the top cell disappears, it will be cleared and reused as the next cell to appear on the bottom. This behaviour makes it rather annoying to test things like this. Residual information left in the view hierarchy from cells that used to be on screen should respond to .exists and if .exists returns true, it should also respond to .hittable.